# Затухание экрана между сценами

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

хочу сделать плавное затухание между сценами по нажатию кнопки,вот только не знаю как сделать,подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вам сюда http://unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=44478

Answer (score 1):

1. создать канвас. Канвас должен быть в режиме оверлея
2. канвас этот сделать .DontDestroyOnLoad - гугл покажет как
3. разместить туда панель черного цвета
4. сделать панель прозрачной

Сначала анимируем убирание прозрачности, потом запускаем асинхронную загрузку иной сцены. Когда сцена загружена - анимируем плавное убавление прозрачности.

безгеморойно анимировать такие вещи из кода можно при помощи библиотеки LeanTween. В том числе по разным функциям графиков (easing) а не только линейное изменение.